# How to include column names along with rows in a result set in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to insert  the column header and corresponding field into another table .

```
Table1 :

col1    col2   col3   col4
1       2       3      4
```

output should look like this:

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C     COL_D    COL_E     COL_F      COL_G    COL_H 
col1    1       col2       2       col3       3         col4     4
```

I tried to apply unpivot, but unpivot gives me the column names vertically not horizontally.

Comment: [tried dynamic query here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987252/how-to-include-column-names-along-with-rows-dynamically-in-oracle),but It doesnot work ,Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Add appropriate aliases from this result however you want.

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN (
                COL1
                ,COL2
                ,COL3
                ,COL4
                ))
    )
PIVOT(  MAX(COl) as C, MAX(VAL) as V FOR COL IN (
             'COL1' as VAL1
            ,'COL2' as VAL2
            ,'COL3' as VAL3
            ,'COL4' as VAL4
            ));
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93dd1/14)

Comment: Hi Kaushik , what approach should  be followed if I dont know the table structure and column names beforehand

Comment: @joe :You can query the tables  `*_tab_columns`  and get the column names, making use of `LISTAGG` to concatenate them. Construct the query dynamically from the resultant string in PL/SQL. google dynamic pivot/unpivot for oracle, you will get many results. You may also use Gordon's approach if you want for a similar exercise.

Comment: [tried dynamic query here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987252/how-to-include-column-names-along-with-rows-dynamically-in-oracle),but It doesnot work ,Please have a look

Comment: @joe : you should try using dynamic PL/SQL

Comment: Hi @Kaushik , [I have edited the question with dynamic sql that I have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987252/how-to-include-column-names-along-with-rows-dynamically-in-oracle)  ,it works for a particular table but throws some error for a table having different structure .Can you please have a look ,I am not sure what I am doing wrong .

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
select 'col1' as col_a, col1 as col_b,
       'col2' as col_c, col2 as col_d,
       'col3' as col_e, col3 as col_f,
       'col4' as col_g, col4 as col_h
from t;
```

Comment: It works only in case I know the column name in table ,In my case I only know the table name and I need to fetch the column names from all_tab_columns ,I am still not sure how I will do it dynamically(not knowing the column names beforehand)

Comment: I can do this ,if I know the table structure beforehand..
select (select column_name from all_tab_columns where COLUMN_ID =1 and table_name = 'TEST1') , col1 ,
(select column_name from all_tab_columns where COLUMN_ID =2 and table_name = 'TEST1') , col2 ,
(select column_name from all_tab_columns where COLUMN_ID =3 and table_name = 'TEST1') , col3 ,
(select column_name from all_tab_columns where COLUMN_ID =4 and table_name = 'TEST1') , col4
from test1