# How to include column names along with rows dynamically in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I am trying to insert  the column header and corresponding field into another table .

```
Table1 :

col1    col2   col3   col4
1       2       3      4
```

output should look like this:

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C     COL_D    COL_E     COL_F      COL_G    COL_H 
col1    1       col2       2       col3       3         col4     4
```

Table1 will be created dynamically , so structure of Table 1 might vary ,for eg .
sometime ,It might be

```
Case1:   

col1    col2   col3   col4
1       2       3      4
```

For Case1 ,output should look like this:

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C     COL_D    COL_E     COL_F      COL_G    COL_H 
col1    1       col2       2       col3       3         col4     4
```

Or it might be 
Case2:

```
  col1    col2   
    1       2
```

For Case2 ,output should look like this:

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C     COL_D    
col1    1       col2       2
```

I got help with the static query for similar requirement in another question in  Stack Overflow,but I was trying to convert the static query to dynamic query.
Static Query :

Static Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
         VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Static Query :

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN (
                COL1
                ,COL2
                ,COL3
                ,COL4
                ))
    )
PIVOT(  MAX(COl) as C, MAX(VAL) as V FOR COL IN (
             'COL1' as VAL1
            ,'COL2' as VAL2
            ,'COL3' as VAL3
            ,'COL4' as VAL4
            ));
```

Output :

```
VAL1_C   VAL1_V    VAL2_C    VAL2_V  VAL3_C   VAL3_V   VAL4_C   VAL4_V
COL1      1        COL2        2       COL3       3      COL4      4
```

As I tried to make the static query dynamic ,I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN (
                select regexp_substr((select * from (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( order by COLUMN_ID) aa
FROM (select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE1'))),'[^,]+', 1, level) "yyy" from dual
   connect by regexp_substr((select * from (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( order by COLUMN_ID) aa
FROM (select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE1'))), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
                ))
    )
PIVOT(  MAX(COl) as C, MAX(VAL) as V FOR COL IN (
             select regexp_substr((select '''' || AA ||'''' from (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP ( order by COLUMN_ID) aa
FROM (select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE1'))),'[^,]+', 1, level) "yyy"  from dual
   connect by regexp_substr((select '''' || AA ||'''' from (SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP ( order by COLUMN_ID) aa
FROM (select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE1'))), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
            ));
```

But this throws error :

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 5
```

I tried using dynamic sql .Below is the dynamic sql I used :

```
declare
  sql_stmt     varchar2(4000);
  pivot_clause1 varchar2(4000);
  pivot_clause2 varchar2(4000);


begin
  SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( order by COLUMN_ID) aa
into   pivot_clause1
  FROM (select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST11') ;

 select * into pivot_clause2 from 
 (  
 select  AA ||'''' aa

 from (SELECT ''''||LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP ( order by COLUMN_ID) aa 
FROM (select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST11')) 

   );

  dbms_output.put_line(pivot_clause1);
   dbms_output.put_line(pivot_clause2);


sql_stmt := 'create table test13 as ('|| 'SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM TEST11
    UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN ( '
                || pivot_clause1 || '
                ))
    )
   PIVOT(  MAX(COl) as C, MAX(VAL) as V FOR COL IN (' || 
           pivot_clause2   || '
            )) 

    )';
   execute immediate sql_stmt  ;


end;
/
```

It is working **fine** for a table having description as below :

```
Name Null Type       
---- ---- ---------- 
COL1      NUMBER(38) 
COL2      NUMBER(38) 
COL3      NUMBER(38) 
COL4      NUMBER(38)
```

But it is **not** working for a table having description :

```
COL1                          DATE          
COL1                          VARCHAR2(100) 
COL1                         VARCHAR2(100) 
COL1                         NUMBER        
COL1                         NUMBER
```

I am getting below error :

```
Error report -
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
ORA-06512: at line 38
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I just learned **unpivot cannot** be used with columns having different datatype,Is there any way around ?
Can someone please help !!

Comment: `PIVOT` doesn't ordinarily work with dynamic column lists. You might be able to get it to work with dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: I've used the technique and the code found here: https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/.  It worked well for me as long as I didn't try to get too fancy (like calling it through DBMS_SQL).

Comment: What would be the output if initial table has many lines? Many lines with repeated column names and new values on each one?

Comment: I tried using dynamic sql ,it is working for some table ,but throwing some error for other tables ,I have edited the question ,please have a look